# C# streamReader ReadLine stucks when executing commands

Tags: c#, cmd, process, readline, streamreader

I try to start to start an external CMD process with some svn commands via a C# console application. Via the process I can read the error output and the normal output. In some cases the .ReadLine() method stucks. Mostly it occurs when I sent this command to the process 'c: & cd "C:\xxxx\xxxx" & svn revert . -R & svn update & svn upgrade & svn merge "https://svn.xxxxxxxxxxx.xx/svn/xxxx/trunk"'. I search on the internet for this problem, but I can't find the right solution. The code below is used to start the process and read the ouput:

```
public static List<string> StartCmdCommand(bool returnOutput, bool printOutput, params string[] commands)
    {
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            CreateNoWindow = false,
            Verb = "runas",
            Arguments = "runas /savecred /profile /user:Admin ",
            UseShellExecute = false

        };

        using (var process = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            foreach (var command in commands)
                process.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);

            process.StandardInput.Flush();
            process.StandardInput.Close();

            List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            String line;
            var standardErrorReader = process.StandardError;
            while ((line = standardErrorReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lines.Add(line);
                if (printOutput)
                    LogHelper.Write(line);
            }

            var standardOutputReader = process.StandardOutput;
            while ((line = standardOutputReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lines.Add(line);
                if (printOutput)
                    LogHelper.Write(line);
            }

            return lines;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Does anybody has experience with this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Kind regards,
Jelle

Comment: You are stuck in the error loop until you receive null

Comment: line is null, but it is hanging on ReadLine(). First I though it was caused by the while loop. When place the ReadLine() outside the while it is also hanging.

Comment: When `ReadLine()` blocks, it means the underlying stream isn't closed and pending data does not (yet) include a newline character. I don't know if `StandardOutput` should automatically be closed when the process ends, or if it's waiting for input for instance.